# Download application/pdf file sent from the backend

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, pdf, axios

I'm struggling with the problem of **downloading a pdf file sent from the backend**.

I get a **blob** response, but when I download and open it, I see **empty** sheets, the number of which is the same as the number of sheets that should be.
Is it possible that this is a coding problem?

At the moment, the backend returns me a pdf in **UTF-8** format, but if I look at other pdf files that I have on my computer, they are in **ANSI**.

backend response preview:

[image: backend response preview]

data and headers:

[image]

empty blanks:

[image]

opened pdf file with notepad:

[image]

```
      const receipt = await this.downloadBookingReceipt({
        bookingNumber: this.bus.bookingReference,
        receiptFormat: 'pdf',
      });

      /**
       * Using "file-saver" library
       */
      const blob = new Blob([receipt.data], { type: 'application/pdf' });
      saveAs(blob, 'receipt.pdf', { autoBom: true });

      /**
       * Using <a>
       */
      const pdfData = new Blob([receipt], { type: 'application/pdf' });
      // Create a link pointing to the ObjectURL containing the blob.
      const pdfUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(pdfData);
      // window.open(pdfUrl);
      const downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
      downloadLink.href = pdfUrl;
      downloadLink.download = `${this.bus.bookingReference}-receipt.pdf`;
      downloadLink.click();
      setTimeout(function () {
        // For Firefox it is necessary to delay revoking the ObjectURL
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(pdfUrl);
      }, 100);
```

Here is **downloadBookingReceipt** function:

```
static async downloadBookingReceipt (axios, { bookingNumber, receiptFormat }) {
    return await axios.get(
      `/v1/booking/${bookingNumber}/receipt/${receiptFormat}`, {
        responseType: 'blob',
      }
    );
  }
```

And server handler for that endpoint:

```
        /**
         * Handler for the booking receipt
         */
        const { data } = await axios.get(BASE_URL + req._parsedUrl.path, {
          headers: {
            AccessToken: TOKEN,
          },
        });
        res.setHeader(
          'content-disposition',
          `attachment; filename="${req.url.slice(9, 18)}-receipt.pdf"`
        );
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
        res.end(data);
        /** */
```

Comment: PDF is a binary format, not UTF-8 or ANSI. If your downloading performs any byte translation on the PDF file then it will be broken by that. You need to treat PDF files as binary.

Comment: @KenS could you please provide more information on how can I fix this?

Comment: No, sorry. I don't know anything about how you are downloading the file, can't follow any of that code. I'm just pointing out that PDF is not encoded the way you think it is. To check if the downloading is the problem, do a byte-by-byte comparison of the original and downloaded file. They should, of course, be identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is how I solved my problem:**

In "request/request" library, the pipe() method is used to download a file from a remote server and directly stream it to a file on the local file system, without having to store the entire response in memory.

*Does axios have the .pipe() function?*

No, the Axios library in JavaScript does not have a built-in .pipe() function.
The .pipe() method is a Node.js stream method that allows you to read data from a readable stream and write it to a writable stream. Axios is a client-side library and does not have access to Node.js streams.

*What did I do?*

```
    axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: BASE_URL + req._parsedUrl.path,
        responseType: 'stream',
        headers: {
            AccessToken: TOKEN,
        },
    })
    .then((response) => {
        response.data.pipe(res);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
    });
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/34314343) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).